# Apache2 Debian Squeeze .htaccess Disabled?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to add a `.htaccess` file to a directory, everything works, the path to `.htpasswd` is working fine.

My contents are:

```
AuthUserFile /root/passwords/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "VNstats"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

The directory `/root/passwords/apache2` is chowned to `www-data`.

However it still refuses to show an authentication box.

I started troubleshooting, and found some tutorials to edit `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` and add `AllowOverride All`. But everytime I do that, I get an error when reloading Apache2 that `AllowOverride All` is not allowed there.

It is a clean apache2 install, do I need to enable some mods? Where can I add `AllowOverride All`?  What am I overlooking?

EDIT: I added this to httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just curious
"The directory /root/passwords/apache2 is chowned to www-data." <= okay, but what is /root permissions ? 700 ?

Comment: yes indeed you are correct

Comment: I moved the folder to /etc/apache2 and now it is working fine :p thanks for reminding me :)